# Why doesn't Wikipedia have extensions?

Tags: html, wikipedia, file-extension

Look at a random wikipedia article like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome, I see that there's no `.html` attached to the end of the address. In fact, if I *do* try to put a .html after it, Wikipedia tells me "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name." How come it doesn't need any file extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you make a call to a website it probably looks like

www.example.com/siteA/index.html

this request just tells the webserver you want to see a resource that is called index.html in siteA.
the website that runs on this server has to determine what you want to see and how the data is loaded.
index.html could be a file in the siteA directory
or
it can be row with the key "index.html" in the siteA-table in your database.

so the part siteA/index.html is just a resource identifier. the grammar of this resource identifier is completely free and is determined per website.

url rewriting is also common to make url easier to read and remember.

for example there could be a rewrite rule to accomplish the following:

if the user enters something like
www.example.com/download/demo.zip

rewrite it so your website sees it like:
www.example.com/download.php?file=demo.zip

Answer (score 4):

More a superuser question?

There is no law saying that an html file has to end in .html or .htm and since wiki generates pages from a database there is really no file page there anyway (except in a cache).

Not having .htm or .php is moresensible - why do you care what technology they use when you ask for a url? It would be like having to put the operating system of the recipient at the end of their email address.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's servers map the url to the page you want. `.html` is just a naming convention that, today is mostly historical from the period of static pages when urls actually were names of files on the server. In fact, there may be no file at all, where the server queries the database and a web framework sends out the html on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is most likely using the Apache module mod_rewrite in order to not have to link paths directly to a file system path.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine#Web_frameworks

However programming languages can also take control of the incoming URLs and return data depending on the structure of the link according to some set of rules, for example the Django web framework employees a [URL dispatcher](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

Answer (score 1):

That's because Wikipedia uses MediaWiki's feature of URL shortening.

Actually when you search for a file it really loads a php file. Try searching for a word that doesn't exist, for example "Pazaz". The URL is `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=pazaz` . Notice `index.php` in the URL.

To tell the truth it's not a MediaWiki feature, it's Apache. For further info http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL .

Answer (score 0):

URL routing is your answer for example in ASP read below [source from](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-controller-overview-cs)

The ASP.NET MVC framework includes a flexible URL routing system that enables you to define URL mapping rules within your applications.  The routing system has two main purposes:

1. Map incoming URLs to the application and route them so that the right Controller and Action method executes to process them
2. Construct outgoing URLs that can be used to call back to Controllers/Actions (for example: form posts,  links, and AJAX calls)

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest that sites like this use some sort of Model View Controller framework similar to [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) where the url 'directories' form a part of a request/url route...

In frameworks that are MVC based, the url 'directories' can dictate what View/Controller to utilise as well as what action should be taken with the data.

eg: shop.com/product/carrots

Where product is a view/controller and carrots is the data. The framework then analyses which action/route to take. Default could be viewing the product information and price of the carrot.